# Plotly - using a number string as xaxis position for annotations

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I am trying to plot and annotate data where the xvalues are given as strings. But plotly always interprets strings as floats if possible when drawing annotations. Plotting the xvalues with add_scatter does not line up with the drawn annotations.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

xdata = ["a","b","c"]
xdata1 = ["10","20","30"]

ydata = [1,3,8]

fig.add_scatter(x=xdata,
                y=ydata)

list_of_all_arrows = []
for i in range(len(xdata)):
    arrow = go.layout.Annotation(dict(
        x=xdata[i],
        y=ydata[i],
        xref="x", yref="y",
        showarrow=True,
        ax=xdata[i],
        ay=ydata[i] + 1,
        axref="x", ayref="y",
        arrowhead=3,
        arrowwidth=1.5)
                    )
    list_of_all_arrows.append(arrow)
    
fig.update_layout(annotations=list_of_all_arrows)
fig.write_html("test.html")
```

When using xdata to plot i get the expected result:
[image: When using xdata to plot i get the expected result.]

But when i use xdata1 plotly tries to interprete it as float only when drawing the annotations:
[image: But when i use xdata1 plotly tries to interprete it as float only when drawing the annotations.]

Is there a way to force it using the numbers as strings?